# NuGet pack command fails on ampersand char (&)

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

The copyright part of our assembly informations contains an ampersand character (&).

In the `nuspec` file we tried to use the variable `$copyright$` to get the value from the dll's assembly info:

`<copyright>$copyright$</copyright>`

The `nuget pack` command fails on this ampersand character with message:

`Beim Analysieren von 'EntityName' ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Zeile 14, Position 55.`

Escaping the ampersand with `&amp;` via assembly info does not work. But doing this directly in the nuspec file works:

`<copyright>Copyright © Dimension Data Germany AG &amp; Co. KG 2018</copyright>`

I assume that when building the assembly, the escaped version is parsed and replaced.

While editing the nuspec file works as workaround, this is not preferred, as we have to update the copyright year twice for each library then.

Any other options?

Comment: What do you mean that `&amp;` via assembly info doesn't work? I just test it with: `[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright &amp; Company")]` and `<copyright>$copyright$</copyright>` in nuspec file, and the output is `<copyright>Copyright &amp; Company</copyright>`

Comment: @Peska: Did you rebuilt the library?

Comment: Yes, I did. Maybe we are looking at two different places. Could you add screenshot where do you expect to see this copyright?

Comment: The output is the error message! `nuget pack` fails and aborts. There is no nuspec file created then. I am not talking about output formatting expectations, but about the `nuget` command failing! ;-)

Comment: Like I said, adding `&amp;` in `[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright &amp; Company")]` works like a charm.

Comment: Ok, thank you Peska, it is working now for me as well. I assumed NuGet takes the `release` library, but it took `debug`. This behaviour is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#additional-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is invalid, as it works with using `&amp;` for ampersands.
I simply confused the build configuration that NuGet is using.

MS docs for this behaviour: [additional options for creating a nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#additional-options)